# Fetching Message From Rabbit MQ using routing key

Tags: rabbitmq

I have created a basic queue and message is routed on basis of routing key.Now I have different domain and domain is routing key for basic queue.for example
domain 
x@yy.com will have one set of message 
t@zz.com will have other set of message
Is there any way so that without knowing the queue name we may fetch the message from queue on basis routing key

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to have queues for each domain in order to be able to consume messages for that domain.